# Binary Search Tree- breadthFirst function Call

Tags: c++, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I have the algorithm for  `void leveltraversal(ostream& out);` 
but i am not sure how to call it in main () . In my Assignment we are not allowed to change the header file. Is there a way to call it without overloading it?

Update:

```
void BST::levelTraversal(ostream& out){
 queue<BST::BinNode*> q;
 BinNode* cur = myRoot;
 BinNode* top = NULL;
 q.push(cur);
 while(q.empty() != false){
  top = q.front();
  if(top->left != NULL){
   q.push(top->left);
  }
  if(top->right !=NULL){
   q.push(top->right);
  }
  out<<top->data;
  q.pop();
 }
}
```

Comment: Is it a free function, or member-function of some class? (I expect the latter though.)

Comment: It is a member of a BST class

Comment: let me try this and ill get back to you .

Answer (score 1):

The parameter, `ostream&`, takes any [output stream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/), e.g. output file. The following example uses the standard output as an `ostream`:

```
BST myBst;
// insert elements into myBst
myBst.leveltraversal( std::cout );
```

Comment: @Steven: I updated the answer and provided a link for `ostream`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the function header, you can define global variables and reference them in both functions (`main` and `leveltraversal`).

Comment: I dont understand how to print it out,

Comment: -1, since you should never use any form of global state as an hidden function input parameter. This kind of parameter is *very* likely to create pain in future code changes.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i have

```
void BST::levelTraversal(ostream& out){
 queue<BST::BinNode*> q;
 BinNode* cur = myRoot;
 BinNode* top = NULL;
 q.push(cur);
 while(q.empty() != false){
  top = q.front();
  if(top->left != NULL){
   q.push(top->left);
  }
  if(top->right !=NULL){
   q.push(top->right);
  }
  out<<top->data;
  q.pop();
 }
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer -- it might be more suitable to "edit" your question, and add this stuff over there. Then, you may delete this answer including this comment.

Comment: Okay - I edited the question for you and added the method definition. You can delete this answer now.

Comment: doesnt give me an option to delete

Comment: Hmm, Okay, Never mind. Lets get back to business. Look at the answers and see if they help you; if not, mention why not.